# Unknown attribute in Controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, require

I'm a bit confused with solving this problem.. i have no Idea what's happening here. If i'm trying to get a New Owner ( click on button redirects to owners#new). But it tells me that :password_confirmation is unknown???

Here's my Error code:

```
unknown attribute 'password_confirmation' for Owner.

Extracted source (around line #46):
44
45
46
47
48
49


def create
@owner = Owner.new(owner_params)
 if @owner.save!
  flash[:notice] = 'You signed up successfully'
  flash[:color]= 'valid'

Rails.root: /Users/xxxx/Devel/Devel xxxx/backend

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/owners_controller.rb:46:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WDAJLTX6467glOnUDJhNkzbdK2rdg+c8ZA1e2tFWfQnqQm2xLVLj    sZEMsvRu3c1i2wYrMh54JzW6YV2GonHYCQ==",
 "owner"=>{"name"=>"Daniel",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
 "commit"=>"Signup"}
```

and here are my owner_params:

```
def owner_params
  params.require(:owner).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :token)
end
```

Hope you can help me quick :)
Greetings, John

Comment: Do you have `password_confirmation` field in `owners` table?

Comment: no. Nor i have the password field.
my app is encoding the password with a salt and after that it gets saved in fields "password_hash" and "password_salt"

Comment: Are you using devise?

Comment: Try adding `attr_accessor :password_confirmation` to `Owner` model.

Comment: no im not using devise.
Thanks!! this should fix it! :) 
i only only wrote: attr_accessor :password
and forget about the confirmation.

Edit: thank you so much!! it's really working.

what a simple error ..

Comment: could u post it as answer so i can mark it as solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90533/discussion-between-coding-john-and-pavan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, adding `attr_accessor :password_confirmation` to `Owner` model should fix your problem.

```
Class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a `Owner` object with all the parameters received from your signup form. However, the keys `password_confirmation` and `commit` for example, are probably not corresponding to an attribute in your `Owner` class.

You should filter the parameters sent to the `new` method:

```
@owner = Owner.new(owner_params.slice('name', 'password'))
```

Comment: It's already fixed. thanks.
 And btw i need the password_confirmation.